# Avoiding for loops to bring table related information for grid display

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following database schema for which I am developing the screen for it.

[image]

I want to display the information in a grid ,for example Desc should be repeated in more than one row and for each row there has to be columns from
**tableC,tableB and tableA** related information.

Right now I am getting every table in  the controller layer using linq "**Include**" related entities and using many foreach loops I am getting the customTable class created and then binding it to the kendo grid.

```
foreach(var a in table C)
{
 foreach(var b in tableB)
 {
   CustomTable c = new CustomTable {
   tableDesc = b.Desc,
   tableBDesc = a.Desc
 }
  }
}

class CustomTable
{
  public string tableDDesc{get;set;}
  public string tableBDesc {get;set;}
}
```

I am thinking is there any better approach for this /Linq syntax to build the customClass in Data access layer itself. Any inputs please?

Comment: Are your loops performing `Cartesian product`? (i.e. no dependency)? In that case you have no option but loops, or `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: I am doing one-to-many mapping and not many to many .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using EF you can do it this way:

```
_context.TableC.Select(x => x.TableB)
   .Select(x => new CustomTable
      {
         tableDesc = x.TableC.Desc,
         tableBDesc = x.Desc
      });
```

This code will generate `SELECT` with `JOIN` and return you `List` of your `CustomTable` objects.

It will get from   `TableB` only rows that have filled `tableC_id` field (NOT NULL).

Answer (score 2):

How about using link projects to bring back results as `CustomTable` class. Something like this

```
 var results = (from tableC in context.TableCs
                              from tableB in context.TableBs
                              where tableB.Id == tableC.Id
                              select new { tableDDesc = tableB.Description, tableBDesc = tableC.Description }
                              ).ToList();

               results.ForEach(obj => new CustomTable{tableDDesc = obj.tableDDesc, tableBDesc = obj.tableBDesc});
```

you can remove the where `tableB.Id == tableC.Id` if not needed